# Reading a CSV file containing greek characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, csv, character-encoding

I am trying to read the data from a CSV file using the following:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.csv").Select(a => a.Split(';'));
```

It works but the fields that contain words are written with Greek charactes and they are presented as symbols. 
How can I set the `Encoding` correctly in order to read those greek characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsy4fhsa.aspx) has overload, which takes [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) along file path

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.csv", Encoding.Unicode)
                .Select(line => line.Split(';'));
```

**Testing:**

```
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\test.csv", "ϗϡϢϣϤ", Encoding.Unicode);

Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\test.csv", Encoding.Unicode));
```

will print:

> ϗϡϢϣϤ

To find out in which encoding the file was actually written, use next snippet:

```
using (var r = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.csv", detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine (r.CurrentEncoding.BodyName);
}
```

for my scenario it will print

```
utf-8
```

Comment: I tried this it didn't work. The characters are shown as ? in a black diamond.

Comment: Tried with unicode. It's worse it didn't even read the number fields this time

Comment: @jayt.dev have you saved your file correctly? I've added example of **saving** and **reading** Greek chars from a file

Comment: Ok now maybe I am not providing the correct encoding. How can I find out what encoding is used in the CSV file?

Comment: Heres is a sample of the CSV

1-Z1GG43C;6;ΑΡΤΕΜΙΔΟΣ;ΑΓΙΑ ΠΑΡΑΣΚΕΥΗ;;
1-ZYD59Q;63;ΨΑΡΩΝ;ΑΓΙΑ ΠΑΡΑΣΚΕΥΗ;;

Comment: Well I am only try to view the contents of var lines through the locals window while debuging. Maybe it is not corectlly presented just in the locals window